# Can vertx EventBus used as "Redis Pub/Sub" for chat Application

Tags: docker, redis, publish-subscribe, vert.x

I have developed a chat Application in react.js with node.js backend and redis - pub/sub for synchronizing message between different docker deployments for scaling.

I am new to Vert.x and trying to move my [chatapp](https://github.com/askeralim/node-vuejs-typescript-vuex-redis-docker-compose) to Vert.x, I found vert.x have event bus, where I can publish and subscribe messages between different verticles in different Docker.

Please provide your valuable feedback..

Comment: In the application I dont want to save the chat messages.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Can I use Vert.x EventBus instead of Redis pub/sub for message synchronization between vert.x docker  deployed in cluster ?

Is it a Good design, or I should go for Redis again ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit of an opinionated question, but I'll try to answer that.

What you need to understand is that clustered EventBus is not some kind of magic. Clustered EventBus is just an abstraction on top of solution such as Hazelcast. Which uses pub/sub mechanism.

So, if you're familiar with Redis and have a working solution, there's not real reason to switch.